# Invalid Outside Procedure

Tags: vba, excel

I searched for solutions on the web for my problem, but couldn't find them. When running the following, I get the error: *Invalid outside procedure* for the second line. Does anyone have suggestions how to solve this? Thank you.

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 37918

If Sheets("nw").Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(6, 3).Value And Sheets("nw").Celss(i, 2) > Sheets("nw").Cells(i, 2).Value Then Sheets("nw").Cells(15, 22).Value = Sheets("nw").Cells(i, 3).Value
End If
Next i

End Sub


Sub NewCost()

End Sub
```

Also, when I place `Sub NewCost()` above `Dim i as integer` I get the error:

> end if without block if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your For loop is outside the Sub()

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub NewCost()

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 37918
        With Sheets("nw")
            If .Cells(i, 1) = .Cells(6, 3) And .Celss(i, 2) > .Cells(i, 2) Then
                .Cells(15, 22) = .Cells(i, 3)
            End If
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the Long. 
However, when I run the formula by @paul bica I still get the error End if without block if.

Comment: @i.c. the way you have your "if" statement structured in your original code, you don't need the "end if" statement.  If you use paul bica's code, you do (the fact that the "then" criteria is on another line).

Comment: I believe it works! Sorry for all the questions, new to vba, but from the site I do not understand how to solve the next error:  Run time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method. @sous2817

Comment: You may want to ask a new question (if this one was solved) and in it post the code related to the next error, but it would be easier if you provide more context describing what the functionality is meant to accomplish

Answer (score 3):

The max value for an Integer is ~32767.  You have to pick a different data type if you want your counter to be that high (perhaps a long?)